# Microsoft.BuildManager not building solution successfully in C#

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, build-automation

I was trying to build a visual studio solution containing C# projects programmatically using the new Microsoft.Build.Framework in .NET 4.5, but the solution doesn't build successfully. Following is the code am using:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;
using Microsoft.Build.Execution;
using Microsoft.Build.Logging;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string solutionPath = @"D:\Work\path_to_solution_file\MySolution.sln";
            ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();

            Dictionary<string, string> globalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            globalProperty.Add("OutputPath", @"C:\Users\Abhishek\Desktop\sample");
            globalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Release");
            globalProperty.Add("Platform", "Any CPU");


            BuildParameters bpar = new BuildParameters(pc);

            BuildRequestData BuildRequest = new BuildRequestData(solutionPath, globalProperty, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);
            BuildResult objresult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(bpar, BuildRequest);

            if (objresult.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Success)
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Failure");
        }
    }
}
```

I have searched several forums but none of the answers provided have worked till now. Can someone please help me out over here? Also, if I try attaching a logger to the BuildParameters object "bpar", I get the following exception when I try debugging the code:

```
System.MissingMethodException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildParameters.set_Loggers(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Microsoft.Build.Framework.ILogger>)'.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Which version of msbuild are you using? Framework-provided ones or NuGet packages (15.*)?

Comment: Framework provided one. I haven't added any package for it. I used Microsoft.Build dlls as provided inside the default .NET framework.

Comment: I don't know how to get them to run but you might want to update to the ones provided via NuGet, since the ones in .NET Framework are very old and might not be able to build projects from vs 2012+